# NET MAUI how to create a hamburger menu

Tags: maui, hamburger-menu

I am trying to create a hamburger menu in xaml, but zero success. I was trying to use the samples provided [here][1], but zero success.

My idea is to create a view model that has a list of FlyoutItems then inject this view model to the AppShell.

```
public partial class ShellViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    public List<FlyoutItem> FlyoutItems { get; private set; } = new List<FlyoutItem>();

    public ShellViewModel()
    {
        AddMenuItems();

    }

    private void AddMenuItems()
    {
        var flyoutItems = new List<FlyoutItem>
        {
            new FlyoutItem
            {
                Title = "Item 1"
            },
            new FlyoutItem
            {
                Title = "Item 2"
            }
        };
        
        FlyoutItems.AddRange(flyoutItems);
    }
}

public partial class AppShell : Shell
{
    private ShellViewModel viewModel => BindingContext as ShellViewModel;

    public AppShell(ShellViewModel viewModel)
    {
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        RegisterRoutes();
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void RegisterRoutes()
    {
        Routing.RegisterRoute(PageRoutes.LoginPage, typeof(LoginPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(PageRoutes.RegisterPage, typeof(RegisterPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(PageRoutes.HomePage, typeof(MainPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(PageRoutes.DetailsPage, typeof(PlayerDetailsPage));
        Routing.RegisterRoute(PageRoutes.AddOrUpdatePage, typeof(AddOrUpdatePlayer));
    }
}
```

In the XAML sometign like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiUI.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiUI"
    xmlns:pages="clr-namespace:MauiUI.Pages">

    <Shell.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CollectionView BindingContext="{x:Reference shell}"
                            IsGrouped="True"
                            ItemsSource="{Binding FlyoutItems}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"
                               TextColor="White"
                               FontSize="18" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Shell.ItemTemplate>

    <ShellContent
        Title="Amazons of Volleyball"
        ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:SplashPage}"
        Route="HomePage" />

</Shell>
```

thnx
[1]: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/flyout?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: "zero success" doesn't really tell us anything useful about the problem.  Are you getting an error or exception?  Does the menu show without any data, or not show at all?  What specifically is happening, or not?

Comment: I mean its not showing, anything

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to create a hamburger menu in xaml, but zero success.

You can add this code in your AppShell.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Shell
    x:Class="MauiUI.AppShell"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MauiUI"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MauiUI.Pages">
    
    <FlyoutItem FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Title="Home"
                      Route="home" 
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MainPage}" />
        <ShellContent Title="NewPage1" 
                      ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate pages:NewPage1}" />
    </FlyoutItem>
    
</Shell>
```

Or you can add this code in your AppShell.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class AppShell : Shell    
{
     public AppShell ()        
     {
            InitializeComponent ();
            
            FlyoutItem flyoutItem = new FlyoutItem ();
            flyoutItem.FlyoutDisplayOptions = FlyoutDisplayOptions.AsMultipleItems;
            
            flyoutItem.Items.Add (new ShellContent () { Title = "NewPage1", Content = new NewPage1 () });
            flyoutItem.Items.Add (new ShellContent () { Title = "home", Content = new MainPage () });
            
            myshell.Items.Add (flyoutItem);
            
     }
      
}
```

Comment: Thnx
How to set the firs page to load depending on do I have a JWT or not int he Shell?

Comment: @Wasyster I think you can set the IsVisible property.